# How to determine the exposure mode used in two photos if they have the same ISO value and the same exposure value?

Tags: exposure, iso, aperture-priority, shutter-priority, shooting-mode

Take a look at the 18<sup>th</sup> and the 19<sup>th</sup> image on [this panasonic lumix fz2500 real world sample gallery](https://www.dpreview.com/samples/1939264024/panasonic-lumix-fz2500-fz2000-real-world-samples-gallery). And while their ISO and EV values are not altered, their Avs and Tvs are inversely changed apiece.
Anyway, I can't figure out what priority mode s/he shot using....

Comment: I just downloaded the accompanying RAW files (Panasonics RW2 format) to look at them and the Metadata, and Lightroom 5 says it cannot convert or use these RAW files. Which is funny; because I had a Panasonic FZ200 myself, and all of the RW2 files from that work with LR.

Comment: @smow Brand new camera probably just isn't supported yet. That's normal.

Comment: At first comment, I was like 'cRap!' but the second one make me sound  'Praise the Sun'

Comment: @mattdm           But, does that mean that, RAWs from FZ2000 don't support Photoshop CS5?  oH! HolY crispy Crap!

Comment: @user152435 Older versions of Adobe products don't directly support newer cameras, only the current versions of Adobe products will. It's what is known as the "Photoshop tax". You can either pay for the newest version or use the Adobe DNG converter to use the files from the newer camera with the older version of Adobe products. Do note there are some drawbacks to converting to DNG which may or may not affect the way you post process your images.

Comment: @user152435 Please see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42468/how-can-i-open-cr2-files-with-photoshop-cs4s-acr/59671#59671   and   http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79876/how-do-i-tell-if-acr-will-work-with-my-camera-and-how-do-i-get-the-correct-versi/79914#79914   and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65030/why-dont-lightroom-or-pse-recognize-cr2-files-from-my-canon-7d-mk-ii-even-thoug/65036#65036

Comment: @user152435 Even though the cameras in those questions are different the concept is the same: Older versions of Adobe products don't directly support cameras newer than that version of the Adobe product. They want to force you to buy the latest upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelClark So, Only Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 will support RAWs from FZ2000?

Comment: @MichaelClark  Is it the "Camera Raw plug-in" that I want to concern about? (Is **it** the Adobe Camera Raw?; In [this table](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html) it's mentioned that RW2 files from this camera are supported by Camera Raw plug-in 9.8 and Lightroom version 6.8..

Comment: And what about Ps?; how do I get to know what **version of Photoshop** supports the RW2s?                                                                                               And also, do I need to separately get the ACR? And then how I 'connect' it with Ps?  Forgive me about these newbie questions.....

Comment: All raw files in the same formats are not equal. All RW2 files are not the same. They are still camera/sensor specific in how they must be handled by raw conversion applications. Even though your version of ACR can handle RW2 files form *some* Panasonic cameras it does not mean it can handle the RW2 files from newer Panasonic cameras.

Comment: You need to determine what version of ACR you need for your camera, then determine what version of PS/Lr/etc. support that version of ACR. The chart says ACR v.9.8 or newer will work with raw files from the FZ2500 and that Lr v.6.8 will work with ACR v.9.8. There's another chart at Adobe somewhere that translates ACR versions to PS versions.

Comment: The answers to the rest of your questions here in the comments are addressed in the questions cited above.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to shutter or aperture priority with fixed ISO, options include:

- full auto or program mode
- a program-shift mode, if the camera has one (from this camera's [manual](ftp://ftp.panasonic.com/camera/om/dmc-fz2500_en_adv_om.pdf), it does not, but other brands do)
- an ISO priority mode, if the camera has one (again, not available on this camera)
- manual

but without asking the photographer or checking the metadata, we can't tell which. In this *particular* case, since the review provides full samples to download with that metadata intact, we can see (using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) or similar) that Shutter Priority was used.

However, if this metadata isn't available and the photographer won't tell you, **there is no way to tell the difference**.

Comment: Ah! but, why can ISO priority be taken?

Comment: @user152435 On this camera, it can't. On a Pentax camera, it could, though.

Comment: On many other cameras from other manufacturers such as Nikon, Canon, Sony, etc. ISO Priority can also be selected. It's nothing unique to Pentax.

Comment: Although I think Pentax is unique in making it a separate mode; on others, it's just `P` but with setting ISO manually, right?

Comment: @mattdm Nope. You can use *Auto ISO* with Tv, Av, and M mode as well as with P mode for many upper tier Canon EOS cameras. I'm pretty sure the upper tier Nikon cameras also offer such use of Auto ISO. You can also set the ISO in P, Tv, Av, and M mode. At least with the Canon models I'm currently using you can also set the ISO range (max and min) available within Auto ISO.